# Check if sum of any 3 integers equal to any of the one element in array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Check if sum of 3 integers equal to any of the one element in array in java . please help me

```
int[] arr={5, 1, 23, 21, 17, 2, 3, 9, 12};
Arrays.sort(arr);
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    System.out.println(+arr[i]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    int sum=arr[i]+arr[i+1]+arr[i+2];
    if(arr[i]==sum)
```

Comment: Sum of what 3 integers? Your code will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you will end up trying to access `arr[arr.length]`, hmm...

Comment: What integer? If you mean 3 consecutive elements in the array then you should edit your question. But what's you question anyway?

Answer (score 1):

you want to check of the sum of any three integers equal to any one of the element in the array? You'll need nested loops

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++){
        for (int k = j+1; k < arr.length; k++){
            int sum = arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k];
            for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++){
                if (sum == arr[index])
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Edit: I guess you can make some optimization if you sort the array first, but you'll still need something similar to the above, with a quadruple nested loop to check all the combinations that sum up to below the largest number

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do something like that ?

```
int[] arr={5, 1, 23, 21, 17, 2, 3, 9, 12};
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++) {
        for(int k=j+1;k<arr.length;k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < arr.length; l++) {
                if (arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]==arr[l]) {
                    System.out.println(arr[i]+"+"+arr[j]+"+"+arr[k]+"="+arr[l]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: complexity of this method is `O(n^4)`. Can it be improved?

Comment: @sanbhat Yes you can, at least to O(n^3 logn). If you sort the array first, you can use binary search to look for the sum of the three numbers inside the array with log(n). But you may also be able to take some advantage of it being sorted and optimize further. But in all you basically have to try almost all combinations. The optimization can only be based on properties of the numbers and can be complicated unless you are willing to do some math